# R language - generate google heat map based on values not density

Tags: r

Given a set of geographic coordinates and values associated with those points, i want to interpolate data and generate heat map on google maps with colors based on the values. Can you guide me to which R packages/functions I can use to achieve this? I have to create this from scratch...the data I have is like ->
latitude ; longitude ; value ; color(i can provide the color input at these points if required from another application).

I am trying to generate something like this ->
http://www.caliper.com/Graphics/maptitude-analysis-hot-spot-heat-mapping.jpg

Comment: So your question is, "Where can I find examples online?" If so, your question will most likely be closed as not being appropriate for this site.

Comment: And what does "based on values not density" mean? Not based on the density of your values?

Comment: By that I meant that I am not intending to create a heat map based on the density of points on the map, rather the values associated with particular points. For example :

Value    Color
0 to 2    Red
2 to 5    Blue
5 to 10  Green
>10       Yellow

And I will have lets say values at 50 points , but I want to interpolate the values to the whole shape of the state and plot colors based on the interpolated values

Comment: See the 2 part tutorial at http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r/ and http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r-part-2/.  The first part shows putting data from a CSV file into a map and the second part applies that to a google map.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create the heatmap I required using ggplot2. I created the grid using gstat:idw and snapped it to the shape of the state using gIntersection. And plotted colors using ggplot2.

However I am not able plot colors according to the values. I want to plot 5 different colors on the map based on values.
0-2 > RED
2-5 > ORANGE
etc.. any suggestions here ?